# How to preserve squash

Tags: squash

I just got a squash from a coworker (he grows it) and it occurs to me that my wife likes to use fresh vegetables for making our own baby food. It also occurs to me that she's out of town for the next two weeks.

What options do I have to preserve this squash in such a manner that she can make baby food when she gets back? If it can sit on the counter for three weeks and be just fine, that works for me. Otherwise, what can I do to cook it that won't render it unusable for baby food? I don't really know what goes into baby food other than I think she steams the veggies so they're soft for our baby.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a summer squash you could maybe try freezing it? Since it's being turned into baby food anyway, preserving crisp, freshness isn't high on the list of priorities?

Disclaimer: I have no experience freezing summer squashes, but a quick google came up with this and it seems to make sense: http://www.pickyourown.org/freezing_summer_squash.htm

A further search reminded me that Alton Brown covers [freezing stuff in an episode of Good Eats](http://www.goodeatsfanpage.com/season12/freezer/frozen_cache_tran.htm). He explains why the above blanching method works for many vegetables.

Comment: I chop and freeze summer squash all the time.  Put it in reasonable sized bags after chopping.  Although, if she steams it, having it chopped and frozen won't work so well for steaming.  Even a summer squash can last for a week or two on the counter, perhaps longer if refrigerated.  As long as it doesn't start to mold (and you keep an eye on that), perhaps it is best just to wait.

Answer (score 0):

What type of squash?  Winter squashes will certainly sit on the counter for several weeks, as long as it stays fairly cool and dry.

Comment: I'm told it's a summer squash. It's very yellow.